# How to assign array data retrieved from state to v-model of array data object in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js

I have a list of applicants from vuex state retrieved using the vuex getters. and from the front end side, I wat to record their respective results as an array and submit their results. but I can't assign the applicants id to v-model.

I have tried using an array and array objects but does not work.
I have tried to loop the list of applicants on the page create and assign to the array data declared in Vue data.

Template Code

```
<template>
<table style="margin-left:10%;">
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Result</th>
          </tr>
          <tr
            v-for="(applicant, key) in getApplicants"
            :key="applicant.applicant_id"
          >
            <td>{{ key + 1 }}</td>
            <td>
              {{ applicant.first_name }} {{ applicant.middle_name }}
              {{ applicant.last_name }}
              <b-form-input v-model="record.applicant_id[key]"></b-form-input>
            </td>
            <td>
              <b-form-input v-model="record.exam_result[key]"></b-form-input>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
<template>
```

script code

```
data() {
    return {
      update: false,
      record: {
        job_vacancy_id: null,
        exam_type_id: null,
        applicant_id: [],
        exam_result: []
      }
    };

methods:{
 save() {
      var object = {
        job_vacancy_id: this.record.job_vacancy_id,
        manpower_requisition_id: this.manpower_requisition_id,
        applicants_id: this.applicants_id,
        exam_result: this.record.exam_result
      };
      console.log(object);
    },
populate() {
      let appliacnts = this.getApplicants;
      for (var i = 0; i <= appliacnts.length; i++) {
        this.record.applicant_id = this.appliacnts.applicant_id[i];
      }
    }
},

created() {
    this.populate();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be `this.record.applicant_id[i] = appliacnts.applicant_id[i]`

```
populate() {
      let appliacnts = this.getApplicants;
      for (var i = 0; i <= appliacnts.length; i++) {
        this.record.applicant_id[i] = appliacnts.applicant_id[i];
      }
    }
},
```

Comment: I have tried this too but it does not work. it responds to me Cannot read property 'applicant_id' of undefined. but the applicant id is the exact attribute name.

Comment: I updated the answer. Changed from `this.appliacnts.applicant_id[i]` to `appliacnts.applicant_id[i]`

Comment: it does not work still. it have tried to log the this.getApplicants collection and it displays data. but when i try to log this.getApplicants.applicant_id it reponds to me undefined and if i add index to it can not read property of 0 undefined the first index number.

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes:

1. `this.record.applicant_id` is an array, so you need an index on the end, before the `=`.
2. `this.appliacnts` should not have a `this`.
3. `this.appliacnts.applicant_id[i]` has the index on the wrong part. It should be before `applicant_id`.
4. `appliacnts` is not spelt correctly. It is consistent though, so it isn't causing any problems.

Correcting for all that we get:

```js
populate() {
  const applicants = this.getApplicants;
  for (var i = 0; i <= applicants.length; i++) {
    this.record.applicant_id[i] = applicants[i].applicant_id;
  }
}
```

It's not a particularly safe implementation though. If it gets called again and the array is shorter it'll leave the old entries in the array. I'd be more inclined to write it like this:

```js
populate() {
  const applicants = this.getApplicants;
  this.record.applicant_id = applicants.map(applicant => applicant.applicant_id);
}
```

Comment: Fabulous Answer! It works correctly now! Thanks to skirtle!